# how to get access to the default spring error JSON

Tags: spring, spring-boot

seems like by default Spring will return a message of:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-01-17T16:12:45.977+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Error processing the request!",
    "path": "/my-endpoint-with-exceptions"
}
```

currently the app is using @RestControllerAdvice with an @ExceptionHandler on each exception. The in each method it uses a ResponseEntity

```
@ExceptionHandler(GenericException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> exceptionHandler(GenericException ex){
 return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
}
```

additionally seems like over time there have been any number of classes which do about the same time as the default which are used.

So would rather use the default Spring JSON however of course do not want to impact currently running code. So my question is for just the GenericException to return the default Spring JSON?

I did try to use ResponseStatusException which did return the JSON but for whatever reason would only return a INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR (500) status even when setting the value in the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own error response and return it from the exception handler method.
Something like this:

**Model:**

```
@Builder
public class ErrorResponse {

    private int status;

    private String error;

    private String message;

    private String path;

    private long timestamp;
}
```

**Handler:**

```
@ExceptionHandler(GenericException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> exceptionHandler(GenericException ex){
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = ErrorResponse.builder()
        .message(ex.getMessage())
        .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value())
        .error(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase())
        .build();

    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Yes I did try that and certainly it would work. but a bit surprised it is such a pain to get to the Spring one

Comment: Yes, I faced the same problem and I found out that I can only customize the message. 
But I think this option looks good.